# Create a user level 777 directory inside root directory /

Tags: linux, permissions, file-permissions, user-permissions

I need to put the Dropbox folder inside the root path, this way:

cd /Dropbox

I can't create first a normal folder because Dropbox automatically creates a Dropbox folder nested in it...
so it would result in this (like It does now)
cd /folder/Dropbox

What would be the problem if I give a "sudo chmod +w /"?
So I could initialize Dropbox inside the root path?
No problem if other files would be written in the / since there are no important files loaded in there, and anyway users wouldn't be allowed to write in the subfolder like /etc. Is that right?

Comment: why do you need to put your Dropbox folder into `/Dropbox`? This seem a very unhealthy requirement for me for a start

Comment: Because I'm trying to get a homogeneous working environment. I work with both osx and linux, and I need all of my shortcuts inside the bashrc to be almost the same, and all of the several paths I always use to be the same (every .conf and a lot of files inside my projects which I keep in my Dropbox folder).

Comment: Environment variables are typically used for this, like `JAVA_HOME` for where java is installed for instance. If I were you my scripts would all read the same env variable. Otherwise all your projects will only be usable by you, that's kind of sad ^^. An intermediate solution is the `/opt/` folder or the `/usr/local/` one, which are less problematic for permissions.

Comment: ok I'll go for env :( Thanks!!